# f2py: how to pass 2 dimension list to fortran 77

Tags: python, arrays, list, fortran, f2py

I have trouble passing 2D arrays to fortran. I want to combine a bunch of not overlapping spectra. First I select the points on the x-axis, then I interpolate all data to this new, common grid. I store the spectra in a 2D list in python.

This works in Python 2.7, but very slow:

```
for i in range(len(wlp)):
  print wlp[i],
  for a in range(len(datax)):
    inrange = 0
    if datax[a][0] >= wlp[i] or datax[a][-1] <= wlp[i]:
      for b in range(len(datax[a])-1):
        if float(datax[a][b]) <= wlp[i] and float(datax[a][b+1]) >= wlp[i]:
          sp = float(datax[a][b]); ep = float(datax[a][b+1])
          delx = ep-sp; dely = float(data[a][b+1])-float(data[a][b])
          ji =  (dely/delx)*(wlp[i]-sp)+float(data[a][b])
          inrange = 1
    if inrange == 0: ji = '?0'
    else: ji = ji * weights[a]
    print ji,
  print
```

The common x-grid is printed in column one and all the interpolated spectra are printed in subsequent columns. If there are some shorter ones out of range, it prints "?0". This helps to set up proper weights for each datapoints later.

I ended up having this fortran subroutine to speed it up with f2py:

```
c wlp = x axis points (wavelength)
c lenwlp = length of list wlp, len(wlp)
c datay = 2D python list with flux
c datax = 2D python list with wavelength
c lendatax = number of spectra, len(datax)
c datax_pl = list of the lengths of all spectra
c weights = list of optional weights
c maxi = length of the longest spectrum   

C============================================================================80
       SUBROUTINE DOIT(wlp,lenwlp,datay,datax,lendatax,datax_pl,
     .                 weights,maxi)
C============================================================================80
       INTEGER  I,a,b,lenwlp,inrange,datax_pl(*),maxi,lendatax
       DOUBLE PRECISION WLP(*),SP,EP,DELY,DELX,ji
       DOUBLE PRECISION WEIGHTS(*)
       DOUBLE PRECISION DATAY(lendatax,maxi)
       DOUBLE PRECISION DATAX(lendatax,maxi)   

 2     FORMAT (E20.12,  1X, $)
 3     FORMAT (A, $)
 4     FORMAT (1X)
       I = 1
       DO WHILE (I.LE.lenwlp)
         WRITE(*,2) WLP(I)
         DO a=1,lendatax
           inrange = 0
           ji = 0.0
           IF (datax(a,1).ge.WLP(I) .or.
     .         datax(a,datax_pl(a)).le.WLP(I)) THEN
             DO b=1,datax_pl(a)-1
               IF (DATAX(a,b).LE.WLP(I) .and.
     .           DATAX(a,b+1).GE.WLP(I)) THEN
                   SP = DATAX(a,b); EP = DATAX(a,b+1)
                   DELX = EP - SP; DELY = datay(a,b+1)-datay(a,b)
                   if (delx.eq.0.0) then
                     ji = datay(a,b)
                   else
                     ji = (DELY/DELX)*(WLP(I)-SP)+datay(a,b)
                   end if
                   inrange = 1
               END IF
             END DO
           END IF
           IF (inrange.eq.0) THEN
             WRITE(*,3) ' ?0'
           ELSE
             WRITE(*,2) ji*WEIGHTS(a)
           END IF
         END DO
         I = I + 1
         write(*,4)
       END DO
       END
```

which compiles with gfortran 4.8 fine. Then I import it in the Python code, set up the lists and run the subroutine:

```
import subroutines
wlp = [...]
data = [[...],[...],[...]]
datax = [[...],[...],[...]]
datax_pl = [...]
weights = [...]
maxi = max(datax_pl)

subroutines.doit(wlp,len(wlp),data,datax,len(datax),datax_pl,weights,maxi)
```

and it returns:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I pass the lists and the length of the longest spectrum (maxi), this should define the maximum dimension in fortran (?). 
I don't need return values, everything is printed on stdout.

The problem must be right at the beginning at the array declarations. I don't have experience with this... any advice is appreciated.

Comment: FWIW this is NOT Fortran 77, you are using features from Fortran 90. You do not show how you call the subroutine, the only thing that is actually important. You cannot just pass Python list, you must use numpy arrays.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment, you cannot pass Python lists to `f2py` procedures. You MUST use `numpy` arrays, which are compatible with Fortran or C arrays.

The error message you show comes from this problem.

You can create the array from a list http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.creation.html